# SQL if random result has a value less than X, return more random results until X value is reached?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I have a table (MySql) where one column is a "Value" between -3 and 3.
What I'm trying to do is this:

1. Pull a random row from the table if it's "Value" is a positive number (1 to 3, in my case - the negative values will be used for something else and aren't relevant here)
2. If the "Value" is 3, display only that row.
3. If the "Value" is 2, display that row, plus another random row with a "Value" of 1.
4. If the "Value" is 1, display that row, plus either one more row with a "Value" of 2, or 2 more rows each with a "Value" of 1.

Or, to put it another way, I need rows listed until the total value of them is 3 - accomplished either by one row with a value of 3, two rows with values of 1 and 2 (or 2 and 1), or three rows with a value of 1 each.

Here's what I have:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE Value>0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; //from all positive Values, get one at random
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE Value BETWEEN 1 AND 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; //from all Values between 1 and 2, get one at random
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE Value=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; //from all Values equal to 1, get one at random
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
  echo $row['A'] . " " . $row['B'] . " " . $row['C'] . " " . $row['Value'];
  echo "<br>";
    }
while($row['Value']<3) 
    {
   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
        {
    echo $row2['A'] . " " . $row2['B'] . " " . $row2['C'] . " " . $row2['Value'];
    echo "<br>";
        }
    }
while($row['Value'] + $row2['Value']<3)
    {
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) 
        {
        echo $row3['A'] . " " . $row3['B'] . " " . $row3['C'] . " " . $row3['Value'];
        echo "<br>";
        }
    }
```

I've tried to put the while statements in different orders, and I keep getting unexpected T_WHILE errors.

The way I have it right now, the code will run and time out with this error:
"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"
AND it doesn't do what I need it to (it's still pulling results if the first "Value" is 3).

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? There must be a better way to accomplish this scenario than what I'm doing, but I'm just not seeing it. Can someone point me the right way? Thanks!

Comment: PHP functions that start with `mysql_` have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead.

Comment: I'm not a php expert, but how are the `while` loops supposed to terminate?

Comment: @joe-frambach Thanks for the suggestion, I'll make the updates once I get it to work correctly (unless using `mysqli_` will fix things for me!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in SQL.  The trick is handling the case where you have 2 + 2.  You have to ignore the second.

The following handles this by defining a `@sum` variable.  This is incremented by `value` as appropriate, with one twist.  If the value misses 3, then the row is ignored:

```
select t.*,
       @sum := if(@prevsum := @sum < 3 and @sum + value > 3, @sum, @sum + value) as thesum
from (select *
      from t
      where value > 0
      order by RAND()
     ) t cross join
     (select @sum := 0, @prevsum := 0) const
having (@sum - value) <= 3 and (@prevsum <> @sum)
```

This maintains the `@prevsum` so it knows to ignore the last row in a case like "2 + 2" or "1 + 1 + 2".

Answer (score 0):

Your `while($row['Value'] < 3)` loop will never end, because you never change `$row`.

I would suggest something like this:

```
$first = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `".$usertable."` where `Value`>0 order by rand() limit 1"));
$result = array($first);
switch($first['Value']) {
case 1:
    $val = rand(1,2);
    $rows = 3-$val; // 2 if $val is 1, 1 if $val is 2
    $q = mysql_query("select * from `".$usertable."` where `Value`=".$val." order by rand() limit ".$rows);
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) $result[] = $r;
    break;
case 2:
    $result[] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `".$usertable."` where `Value`=1 order by rand() limit 1"));
    break;
// case 3 does nothing special
}
// result rows are in $result[] array.
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm still having issues with the display part of it. I added `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
  echo $row['A'] . " " . $row['B'] . " " . $row['C'] . " " . $row['Value'];
  echo "<br>";
 }
` to the end of your code block, but I get this: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/content/09/10184409/html/trait2.php on line 27` where line 27 is my `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) `

Comment: `$result` is an array, not a MySQL result. After you've used my code, use `foreach($result as $row)` and you can output it.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql_query's are at wrong place.

You should realize, that query is executed at the point, where mysql_query is called, hence you are in your while's looping trough the same row over and over...

Thats why you are getting maximum exec time...

**EDIT**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE Value>0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; //from all positive Values, get one at random
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE Value BETWEEN 1 AND 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; //from all Values between 1 and 2, get one at random
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE Value=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; //from all Values equal to 1, get one at random


$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['A'] . " " . $row['B'] . " " . $row['C'] . " " . $row['Value'];
echo "<br>";

if ($row['Value'] < 3)
{
    switch($row['Value'])
    {
        case 2: //If the "Value" is 2, display that row, plus another random row with a "Value" of 1. - thats your query3
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
            $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
            echo $row3['A'] . " " . $row3['B'] . " " . $row3['C'] . " " . $row3['Value'];
            break;

        case 1: //If the "Value" is 1, display that row, plus either one more row with a "Value" of 2, or 2 more rows each with a "Value" of 1. - your query2
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
            echo $row2['A'] . " " . $row2['B'] . " " . $row2['C'] . " " . $row2['Value'];
            if($row2['Value'] == 1)
            { //select another row with value of 1 - your query3
                $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
                $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
                echo $row3['A'] . " " . $row3['B'] . " " . $row3['C'] . " " . $row3['Value'];
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Please note, that this code can select one row more times - you didn't mentiond, that rows should be unique. If you will need unique rows, you need to alter sql code to not select allready selected rows (ie. by some unique identifier or by complete result set returned)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how to do it the right way? I knew my code was wrong, and was looking for some suggestions.